# Limit of $(1 + \frac{1}{5x})^{7x}$ as $x$ approaches $0$

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I have to find the limit of the function given in the title. My calculator says that the limit is undefined, wolfram alpha says it is 1, I am confused but I think that the calculator is right since $\frac{1}{5x}$ is also undefined as $x$ approaches $0$. Can you guys tell me what is the correct limit?

Comment: The limit is $e^0=1$ because $a^b=e^{b\ln a}$ and $\lim_{x\to0}(7x\ln(1+1/5x))=-7\lim_{x\to0}(x\ln x)=0.$

Comment: The most immediate concern I have is that the limit from the left is undefined by itself.  Is this supposed to be the limit as $x \to 0^+$?

Comment: @BrianMoehring no the task only tells to calculate the limit in general

Comment: @BrianMoehring A case could be made that it is implicit that the right hand limit is being asked for.  The justification would be that the domain of the function $~\displaystyle f(x) = \left(1 + \frac{5}{x}\right)^{7x}~$ does not include any element in $\Bbb{R_{-5 < x < 0}}.$  My understanding is that when calculating the limit of (for example) a function $~f(x), ~$  the values are restricted to the domain of the function.

Comment: @BrianMoehring Re last comment, an alternative perspective is that some of the elements in $\Bbb{R_{-5 < x < 0}}$ are in the domain of $f(x)$, and that when calculating the LHS limit, only those values are relevant.